# Disable ListView Ripple animation in Xamarin

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**How to disable Xamarin UWP ListView Ripple animation?**

[image]

We are using ListView. And inside it we have Labels.

```
<ListView x:Name="Test" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElementAndDataTemplate"
                      SeparatorVisibility="Default">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell Appearing="Cell_OnAppearing">
                            <Grid ColumnSpacing="0">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <!-- I have approx 20-25 columns here -->
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <!-- Label for 20-25 columns -->
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: It looks likes table head style, what control you have used, please share your code segment.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT: We are using ListView. And inside it we have Labels.